# Simple condcional if no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Tengo un código que obtuve de una página para hacer ejercicios pero el último condicional if no hace nada, cuando el contenido claramente debería resultar en true.

**El código:**

```
var numero1 = 5;
var numero2 = 8;

if (numero1 < numero2) {
  document.write("numero1 no es mayor que numero2 <br>");
}
if (numero2 > 0) {
  document.write("numero2 es positivo <br>");
}
if (numero1 < 0 || numero1 != 0) {
  document.write("numero1 es negativo o distinto de cero <br>");
}
if (numero1 + 1 < numero2) {
  documento.write("Incrementar en 1 unidad el valor de numero1 no lo hace mayor o igual que numero2");
}
```

todos los condicionales imprimen su resultado correctamente menos el último, busqué la solución del ejercicio en línea y la solución sería cambiar  `if(numero1 + 1 < numero2)` por `if(++numero1 < numero2)`.

Pero ya apliqué esa solución y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo; el último condicional no se imprime.

Comment: Tienes un typo, cuidado con esos detalles por qué tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Comment: *if (numero < 0 || numero != 0)* es lo mismo que *if (numero != 0)* Revisa tu lógica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var numero1 = 5;
var numero2 = 8;

if (numero1 < numero2) {
  document.write("numero1 no es mayor que numero2 <br>");
}
if (numero2 > 0) {
  document.write("numero2 es positivo <br>");
}
if (numero1 != 0) {
  document.write("numero1 es negativo o distinto de cero <br>");
}
if (numero1 + 1 < numero2) {
  document.write("Incrementar en 1 unidad el valor de numero1 no lo hace mayor o igual que numero2");
}
```

El único error que había era que en el ultimo `if` pusiste `documento` en ves de `document`. Al tener este problema te sugiero que para escribir código uses editores de código, ya que estos te marcan este tipo de errores. Hay miles de editores de código, como VSC (Visual Studio Code), Sublime  Text, Atom, etcétera.

Comment: estoy usando visual studio code pero no tenía marcado ningún error, hay algún atributo que deba instalarle para que me los pueda marcar?